# Phrases only differing by spaces

Tags: terminology

Is there a name for phrases that differ from another only by spaces? For example, "superb rain" differs from "super brain" only by spaces. So if the name of this is X, we could say "superb rain" is an X of "super brain". (Just like we could say "superb rain" is an *anagram* of "arisen burp".)

Comment: Some good crossword clues depend on such reformulations, but I've not seen a convincing term for this type of clue.

Comment: What do you mean by "spaces"?

Comment: @Lambie Like the space between "superb" and "rain".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth they are a very simple anagram, as crossword answers do not contain spaces.

Comment: It's called [rebracketing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebracketing). See the linked duplicate. If this does not provide the answer you're looking for, just let us know why not and we can look into reopening it for you.

Comment: @Weather Vane Yes, 'anagram' is a (gross) hypernym.

Comment: Surely the linguistics terms refer to semantic changes over time rather the accidental similarities of strings (as used in crosswords)? eg 'It's a cert he's a strange child' [4,2].

Comment: @tchrist Right, seems to be a special case of that (and also a special case of anagrams), as I'm not interested in cases like "an eke name > a nickname" where letters change. I was hoping the name would help me google other funny examples, like googling "funny anagrams" does. So far it hasn't helped. I guess it's not popular. Background btw is that stack exchange removes spaces when you let it auto-complete user names, so for example if you call yourself "superb rain", others will write "@superbrain" and then yet others are likely to misinterpret that as "super brain", which I find amusing.

Comment: But calling yourself "superb rain" can only be a rebracketing of "super brain". Who says "superb rain"?

Comment: @WeatherVane Not sure what you mean. What does that matter?

Comment: I mean that the writer *intends* it to be read as "super brain".

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes, that's what makes that case fun. And "superb rain" is a perfectly valid phrase.